# how to connect redshift database to a bash script running on ec2 instance

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

I have couple of sql queries and I want to run them against amazon redhshift , The base script will be on my ec2 instance and will be triggered from there. How do I provide the connection to the database and the run the bunch of sql scripts ? Please guide

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-from-psql.html - Literally the first result when I google "redshift sql from shell"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to install postgres on the ec2 instance and then use the psql command line tools to connect to Redshift.

Install postgres (yum and apt-get, pick the appropriate one for your Linux type):

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Here's a line from one of my bash scripts that does this.  Check out the psql man page for all the options and ways to connect.

```
PGPASSWORD="$RS_password" psql -a -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -h "$RS_DNS" -v schema=public -p "$RS_port_no" -U "$RS_user" -d "$RS_db" -f /tmp/math_$$.SQL  || { echo psql command 1 failed ; exit 1; }
```

There is also a -c option to pass the SQL on the command line.

Comment: I was thinking to sechdule the same in airflow actually . Using java.jar files and initiate form there actually. I will definitely post more queries if I need it. Thanks a lot for the feedback